# Obtener los datos de un listview personalizado

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, studio

Pasa que tengo un proyecto donde mostrará información de la base de datos(SQLite) a un listview personalizado y ya la tengo hecho, pero ahora quiero obtener los datos al seleccionar una fila del listview para así poder hacer consultas, no muestro código por qué no tengo esa parte, en el listview personalizado tengo 5 textviews  y un imageview, se los agradezco mucho por su ayuda

Comment: Agrega el código de lo que has intentado así tenga errores.

Comment: Si quieres obtener sólo los datos de una celda, entonces añade un listener en la vista que recibe el viewHolder, añádelo en el constructor y invoque un callback dónde le pasas el id de tu objeto o todo el objeto, según lo que necesites.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
}}
```

Dentro del onItemClick puedes usar el obj parent para llegar al item del adaptador en la posicion que indica el int position